# Handling Custom ComboBox in pywinauto

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am writing a script to select a region in a ComboBox. I can use `app.dialog['Region:ComboBox'].select(index)`, but not `app.dialog['Region:ComboBox'].select('string')`. I notice the ComboBox is custom and is generated real time. How can I select the proper option using a string? The string would be a region like US West, US East, etc.

```
   |    | GroupBox - 'Preferences'    (L811, T456, R1108, B593)
   |    | ['PreferencesGroupBox', 'Preferences', 'GroupBox', 'GroupBox0', 'GroupBox1']
   |    | child_window(title="Preferences", control_type="Group")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'PREFERENCES'    (L817, T462, R1102, B476)
   |    |    | ['PREFERENCES', 'PREFERENCESStatic', 'Static25']
   |    |    | child_window(title="PREFERENCES", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Region Text:'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    | ['Region Text:Static', 'Region Text:', 'Static26']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Region Text:", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    | ['Static27']
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Region:'    (L822, T498, R937, B512)
   |    |    | ['Region:Static', 'Region:', 'Static28']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Region:", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Custom - ''    (L947, T492, R1097, B518)
   |    |    | ['Custom3', 'Region:Custom']
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ComboBox - ''    (L947, T492, R1097, B518)
   |    |    |    | ['ComboBox', 'Region:ComboBox', 'ComboBoxESRI.ArcGIS.Azure.IaaS.Interfaces.RegionInfo']
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Edit - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Edit', 'Edit0', 'Edit1']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="PART_EditableTextBox", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Static - 'Remote Desktop Port:'    (L822, T534, R937, B548)
   |    |    | ['Remote Desktop Port:', 'Remote Desktop Port:Static', 'Static29']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Remote Desktop Port:", control_type="Text")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Edit - '3389'    (L947, T528, R1097, B554)
   |    |    | ['Edit2', 'Remote Desktop Port:Edit']
   |    |    | child_window(title="3389", control_type="Edit")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar', 'ScrollBar0', 'ScrollBar1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="VerticalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | ScrollBar - ''    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    | ['ScrollBar2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(auto_id="HorizontalScrollBar", control_type="ScrollBar")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Button - 'r'    (L0, T0, R0, B0)
   |    |    |    | ['r', 'Button8', 'rButton']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="r", auto_id="PART_ClearText", control_type="Button")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | CheckBox - 'Track application usage anonymously'    (L822, T564, R1097, B582)
   |    |    | ['Track application usage anonymously', 'CheckBox', 'Track application usage anonymouslyCheckBox', 'Track application usage anonymously0', 'Track application usage anonymously1']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Track application usage anonymously", control_type="CheckBox")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Static - 'Track application usage anonymously'    (L846, T565, R1043, B581)
   |    |    |    | ['Track application usage anonymously2', 'Track application usage anonymouslyStatic', 'Static30']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Track application usage anonymously", control_type="Text")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I implemented it. This function emulates the select() function more efficiently.

```
def comboselect(combo,sel):
    combo.type_keys("{ENTER}")          # Selects the combo box
    texts = combo.texts()               #gets all texts available in combo box
    try:
        index = texts.index(str(sel))   #find index of required selection
    except ValueError:
        return False
    sel_index = combo.selected_index()  # find current index of combo
    if(index>sel_index):
        combo.type_keys("{DOWN}"*abs(index-sel_index))
    else:
        combo.type_keys("{UP}"*abs(index-sel_index))
    return True
```